# Is there an audio processing library/API that contains all standard features of a digital audio workstation?

Tags: audio

I need an audio processing library/API (in any programming language, preferably Java or Python) that is able to do things to sound waves such as: sum/mix sources together, apply EQ, dynamic EQ where you can change a frequency peak or amplitude setting over time, pitch shift, distortion, and convolution reverb, all programmatically without any need for a user interface.

Someone asked "If there were, why would there be a market for premium commercial DAW software?" Obviously this wouldn't be for the actual music-making composer or sound engineer because it would be unusable (it wouldn't have a GUI). I need it to automatically manipulate sound so I can churn out millions of random not-necessarily-musical sound files, without a GUI.

This is not same as the "OpenCV for audio" question, because I don't need intelligent audio feature extraction; I just need the standard features of DAW such as EQ and convolutional reverb, available as an API call, like soundFile.applyEq(myEq).applyConvReverb(myReverb);

Comment: You might receive more useful answers at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (?)

Answer (score 1):

For python, I'd try out:

1. [pydub](http://pydub.com) for basic audio manipulation and arrangement (slicing, concatenation, fading, repeating, etc).
2. For effects processing, [pyo](http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/software/pyo/) is a good python signal processing module with a musical focus. Here's a comprehensive [review](http://www.matthieuamiguet.ch/blog/diy-guitar-effects-python), with inline clips.

Together you should be able to get good coverage of most DAW functions. There are also fantastic python audio libraries like [librosa](https://github.com/bmcfee/librosa), in case you do decide to do any feature extraction or audio analysis. Good luck!